# Taking square photo with react native camera

Tags: ios, camera, react-native, base64, react-native-camera

By default the `react-native-camera` takes photos in standard aspect ratio of the phone and outputs them in **Base64 png**, if the `Camera.constants.CaptureTarget.memory` target is set.

I am looking for a way to create **square** photos - either directly using the camera, or by converting the captured `imagedata`. Not sure if something like that is possible with React Native, or I should go entirely for native code instead.

The `aspect` prop changes only how the camera image is displayed in the viewfinder.

Here is my code:

```
<Camera
  ref={(cam) => {
    this.cam = cam;
  }}
  captureAudio={false}
  captureTarget={Camera.constants.CaptureTarget.memory}
  aspect={Camera.constants.Aspect.fill}>
</Camera>;

async takePicture() {
  var imagedata;
  try {
    var imagedata = await this.cam.capture();// Base64 png, not square
  } catch (err) {
    throw err;
  }
  return imagedata;
}
```

Comment: Check this built-in utility - [ImageEditor.cropImage](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/imageeditor.html), I have not used it, but it look that you can use it to crop the image to square.

Comment: It looks like the ImageEditor works only with images in the ImageStore. For a Base64 image passed into the URI parameter it throws `No suitable image URL loader found for (null)` error.

Comment: @PeterGerhat: Have looked https://github.com/ivpusic/react-native-image-crop-picker ?

Answer (score 5):

**Use the getSize method on the Image and pass the data to the cropImage method of ImageEditor.**

Looking at the cropData object, you can see that I pass the width of the image as the value for both the width and the height, creating a perfect square image.

Offsetting the Y axis is necessary so that the center of the image is cropped, rather than the top. Dividing the height in half, and then subtracting half of the size of the image from that number ((h/2) - (w/2)), should ensure that you're always cropping from the center of the image, no matter what device you're using.

```js
Image.getSize(originalImage, (w, h) => {
  const cropData = {
    offset: {
      x: 0,
      y: h / 2 - w / 2,
    },
    size: {
      width: w,
      height: w,
    },
  };
  ImageEditor.cropImage(
    originalImage,
    cropData,
    successURI => {
      // successURI contains your newly cropped image
    },
    error => {
      console.log(error);
    },
  );
});
```

Comment: How come that calculation always gets the center of the image? I can't seem to make sense out of it :(